# Failed to post notification on channel “null”

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an App which can send notifications to the users but since the new PlayStore Updates needs to match targetSdkVersion 26 the notifications dont work anymore with the error toast Failed to post notification on channel “null”. There are some threads about it but i didnt get the solution. Here is my actual FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setContentText(notification_message);


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to make it working again? It would be good if it also works for devices from sdk 24 up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android Oreo, you need a Channel to send your notifications.
You can do something like this (not tested) :

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

  public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                        .setContentText(notification_message);


        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
        resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);

            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotifyMgr.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID); causes Cannot resolve method 'setChannelId(java.lang.String)'

Comment: Are you using the last AppCompat ? Or, at least, the 26.0.2 ?

Comment: Works when the app is open. if the app is closed or in background the error message Failed to post notification on channel “null” appears again.

Comment: nmv Ive updated firebase messaging to 11.8.0 and it works now. thanks

Comment: Ok, cool. If my answer suits you, do not hesitate to upvote it: it could help someone else in the future ;)

Comment: I have done, but: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: It works when the app is in background but get the Failed to post notification on channel “null” message when the app is open